# Only Allow Objects with Unique Name - Java

Tags: java

I am making an inventory system.

I want to ensure that objects I am creating (Ingredients) all have unique names. In other words, I want to make sure that there are never two Ingredients that have the same name in the whole program. Currently I have the following class:

```
package ingredient;

import java.util.HashSet;

public class Ingredient {

private final String name;
private final double price;

private static HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String> ();

private Ingredient(String ingr_name, double ingr_price) {
    name = ingr_name;
    price = ingr_price;
}

public static Ingredient createIngredient(String ingr_name, double ingr_price) {
    if (names.contains(ingr_name)) {
        return null;
    } else {
        names.add(ingr_name);
        return new Ingredient(ingr_name, ingr_price);
    }
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
```

}

Then, when I go to actually make new ingredients, I make statements such as :

```
Ingredient egg = Ingredient.createIngredient("egg", 1);
```

Is this okay design? I suppose I am concerned because returning "NULL" might not be the best practice here.

Comment: a) in `createIngredient(...)` why do you return `null` instead of the already created `Ingredient`? b) This is basically the Java-version of a memory leak, since an `Ingredient` is never garbage-collected, even if it is only referenced by your static field `names`. You might want to take a look at [this](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references).

Comment: This is fine if you're just experimenting, however, if you ever need that code to run in a multi-threaded system, there will be issues.

Comment: @Turing85 in regards to (a) ... Would an alternative be to store actual pointers to already created ingredients in a set? (What I am currently doing with their names)

Comment: @the_real_jiub this would be my approach, yes. But please look at b), since this gets even more important.

Comment: Answering your question whether this design is okay, my opinion (yes opinion) is no. You are mixing a factory (the one creating ingredients) with the actual `Ingredient` class. If you are looking for a solid design approach, make `Ingredient` a class on its own and use (create) an `IngredientFactory` to create a new `Ingredient` or return an existing `Ingredient`. Please make sure you change your `HashSet<String>` to `HashSet<Ingredient>` instead of string, since it also has a price element.

Comment: I would change createIngredient to getOrCreateIngredient and return the existing object if it exists. (Optionally updating the price)

Comment: @Turing85 thanks for that link, that is super interesting! I will edit my code above using weak references.

Comment: @avk How can I separate the factory from the ingredient if I want the ingredient to have a private constructor??

Comment: @the_real_jiub - Make it an inner class, that means you create the Ingredient class within the IngredientFactory and only allow the Factory to create instances of Ingredient.

Comment: @the_real_jiub - Also have a look at the builder-design-pattern. That could give you some idea on how to create a class object that cannot be instantiated using the `new` clause

Comment: Just a side note, it might make sense to have your prices independent of the ingredient if you would like to have ingredients be unique.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies everyone, I learned a lot! Ultimately, I decided to go with the answer given by hoyah_hayoh below.

Comment: as far as as returning null is concerned, returning is not a bad practice, its the best way to know if API call has worked or not. if (blockingQueue.poll() != null ) then doThat(); etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant comment, but whatever...
I would go about this by storing all of the Ingredients in a different class, then you wouldn't need all this static nonsense. In the class where you actually create a new Ingredient (`Ingredient egg = Ingredient.createIngredient("egg", 1);`) you could maybe create an `ArrayList` of ingredients like so:

```
ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then when you make a new `Ingredient` you would just have to make sure you add it to the `ArrayList`and when you do so, check that none of the ingredients are already there, maybe something like this:

```
createIngredient("egg", 1);
```

or

```
Ingredient egg = createIngredient("egg", 1);
```

...

```
private Ingredient createIngredient(String ingr_name, double ingr_price){
    for(Ingredient i : ingredients){
        if(i.getName().equals(ingr_name)){
            return null;
        }
    }
    Ingredient newing = new Ingredient(ingr_name, ingr_price);
    ingredients.add(newing);
    return newing;
}
```

Then the `Ingredient` class could be cut down to something like this:

```
package ingredient;

public class Ingredient {

    private final String name;
    private final double price;

    public Ingredient(String ingr_name, double ingr_price) {
        name = ingr_name;
        price = ingr_price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

And then you could access each individual `Ingredient`with a method to run through the `ArrayList` and find the `Ingredient` with the name your looking for:

```
public Ingredient findIngredient(String name){
    for(Ingredient i : ingredients){
        if(i.getName().equals(name)){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I think this is simplest, so I went with this. Essentially, I have another class, an actual inventory, and when I go to add to it, I just check to make sure there isnt an ingredient of the same name. If there is, I throw an exception. Thanks!

Comment: I use this way of doing it alot :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend either

A) returning the already created ingredient

Or if that would confuse the caller,

B) throwing an exception

This can be a simple `IllegalArgumentsException`, or depending on your needs, a custom exception class.